# TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'data') at errorHandler

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, express, prisma

I am receiving the following error whenever I try to make a **post, patch, or put** request. No problem for get requests.

```
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'data')
     at errorHandler (/home/joe/Documents/myproject/server/dist/middleware/errorHandler.js:28:22)
     at newFn (/home/joe/Documents/myproject/server/node_modules/express-async-errors/index.js:16:20)
     at Layer.handle_error (/home/joe/Documents/myproject/server/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:71:5)
     at trim_prefix (/home/joe/Documents/myproject/server/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:326:13)
     at /home/joe/Documents/myproject/server/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:286:9
     at Function.process_params (/home/joe/Documents/myproject/server/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:346:12)
     at next (/home/joe/Documents/myproject/server/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:280:10)
     at Immediate.<anonymous> (/home/joe/Documents/myproject/server/node_modules/express/lib/application.js:240:9)
     at Immediate.<anonymous> (/home/joe/Documents/myproject/server/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:646:15)
     at process.processImmediate (node:internal/timers:473:21)
```

Here is one of the functions.

path `/src/routes/category.controller.ts`

```
import { Request, Response } from "express";
import prisma from "../../db/connect";
import { NotFoundError } from "../../errors";

export async function createManyCategories(req: Request, res: Response) {
const body = req.body;

const category = await prisma.category.createMany({
        data: [...body],
    });
    if (!category) {
        throw new NotFoundError("category not created");
    }
    return res.status(200).json(category);
}
```

**routes of the function**
path `/src/routes/category.router.ts`

```
import express from "express";
import {
    createCategory,
    createManyCategories,
    getCategories,
} from "./category.controller";

const categoryRouter = express.Router();

categoryRouter.route("/").post(createCategory).get(getCategories);

export default categoryRouter
```

**main app file**

path `/src/app.ts`

```
import dotenv from "dotenv";
import "express-async-errors";
import express, { Express } from "express";
import errorHandler from "./middleware/errorHandler";
import categoryRouter from "./routes/category/category.router";

dotenv.config();

const app: Express = express();

app.use(express.json());
app.use("/category", categoryRouter);

app.use(errorHandler);
```

path `/src/middleware/errorHandler.ts`

```
import { Request, Response, NextFunction, ErrorRequestHandler } from "express";

function errorHandler(
    err: ErrorObj,
    req: Request,
    res: Response,
    next: NextFunction
) {
    let customError: CustomErr = {
        statusCode: err.statusCode || 500,
        msg: err.message || "Something went wrong please try again later",
    };
    //duplicate error
    if (err.code && err.code === "P2002") {
        customError.msg = `${Object.values(err.meta)} already exists`;
        customError.statusCode = 400;
    }
      //cast error
  if (err.name === "CastError") {
    customError.msg = `${err.value} is not a valid id`;
    customError.statusCode = 400;
  }

  //validation errors
  if (err.name === "ValidationError") {
    customError.msg = `${Object.values(err.errors)}`;
    customError.statusCode = 400;
  }
  // multer error
  if (err.code === "LIMIT_FILE_SIZE") {
    customError.msg = "File size too large, maxsize: 3mb";
    customError.statusCode = 400;
  }

  if (err.response.data.errorCode === "500.001.1001") {
    customError.msg = err.response.data.errorMessage;
    customError.statusCode = 400;
  }
    console.log(err);
    return res.status(customError.statusCode).json({ error: customError.msg });
}
```

path `/src/db/connect.ts`

```
import { PrismaClient } from "@prisma/client";

const prisma = new PrismaClient();

export default prisma;
```

**custom error**

path `/src/errors/index.ts`

```
class CustomApiError extends Error{
    constructor(message: string){
        super(message)
    }
}

export class NotFoundError extends CustomApiError{
    statusCode: number
    constructor(message: string){
        super(message)
        this.statusCode = 404
    }
}
```

I have tried uninstalling express, prisma, and express-async-errors and then installing them and nothing has changed.
I have also tried commenting the prisma logic part as shown below but still geting the error.

```
async function createManyCategories(req: Request, res: Response) {
    const body = req.body;
    return res.status(200).json(body);
    
    // const category = await prisma.category.createMany({
    //     data: [...body]
    // });
    // if (!category) {
    //     throw new NotFoundError("category not created");
    // }
    // return res.status(200).json(category);
}
```

Comment: I think there is some code you are omitting from what you have shown it seems to me the error is occuring in the errorHandler what is the code at `// ...`

Comment: I think the error is occuring on line `if (err.response.data.errorCode === "500.001.1001") {` you can of course also check in the built files and see where the error is occuring but what i;m thinking is that the reponse object doesn't exist on the err object so it is undefined and then you look for a prop data on undefined which throws an exception

Answer (score 1):

*Hi guys,*
for me its looks like the error is thrown in the "errorHandler" function.
Or even more precisely in the following if statement condition:

```
if (err.response.data.errorCode === "500.001.1001") {
    customError.msg = err.response.data.errorMessage;
    customError.statusCode = 400;
}
```

It seems that "err.response" is *undefined*.
You could start debugging with the following if statement conditions and analysis how and when exactly the error behaves:

```
if (
    err.response && //Check if "err.response" is undefined
    err.response.data && //Additional check if "err.response.data" is undefined
    err.response.data.errorCode === "500.001.1001"
) {
    customError.msg = err.response.data.errorMessage;
    customError.statusCode = 400;
} else {
    //your analysis and debugging point
}
```

You gave us **a lot of code** and unfortunately not only code that breaks down the problem to **a small, quickly testable part**, otherwise I would try the solution myself and gave you a better and safer feedback.
*I wish you all a nice day!*